# I'm getting AnalysisException: [UNRESOLVED_COLUMN.WITHOUT_SUGGESTION], but the column is there

Tags: sql, databricks

I'm getting this error message when trying to run the query below:
"AnalysisException: [UNRESOLVED_COLUMN.WITHOUT_SUGGESTION] A column or function parameter with name `user_id` cannot be resolved. ; line 43 pos 17;", but the `user_id` column is right there. Databricks points out that this is the line with an error:

[image]

If I delete this `tb_final` block and end the query with `select * from tb_exit_last_month_join_profile` I can see the column `user_id`:

[image]

I've tried changing the column's name. It didn't work though.

The table `refined.vwm_dash_user_activity_granular` comes from databricks' data lake, whereas `temp_table_website_profile_cortex_content` is a temporary table created with python code `spark.sql(get_website_user_profile(d)).createOrReplaceTempView('temp_table_website_profile_cortex_content')`. `get_website_user_profile(d)` is just a function that returns a query as a string and `d` is a string date.

Here is the query I'm running:

```
%sql
WITH tb_paginas_saida as
(
  select *, case when lead_user_entrance = 1 or lead_user_entrance is null then 1 else 0 end user_exit
  from
  (
    select *, lead(user_entrance) over(partition by userId order by dateHourMinute, user_entrance desc) as lead_user_entrance
    from refined.vwm_dash_user_activity_granular
    where not outlier_flag and user_entrance = 1 and dateHourMinute is not null and userId is not null
          and pagePath is not null and month(date) = month(DATEADD(day, -1, date('2023-02-01'))) and year(date) = year(DATEADD(day, -1, date('2023-02-01')))
  )
),      
tb_exit_last_month_per_page_and_user as
(
  -- Principal página por usuário
  select userId, pagePath
  from
  (
    select userId, pagePath, row_number() over(partition by userId order by count_pages_exit desc) as user_page_rank
    from
    (
      select userId, pagePath, count(*) as count_pages_exit
      from tb_paginas_saida
      group by userId, pagePath
    )
  )
  where user_page_rank = 1        
),
tb_exit_last_month_join_profile as
(
  select a1.userId as user_id, a1.pagePath, a2.tag_frequencia_de_acessos_30_dias
  from tb_exit_last_month_per_page_and_user as a1
  join temp_table_website_profile_cortex_content as a2 on a1.userId = a2.userId
),
tb_final as
(
  select tag_frequencia_de_acessos_30_dias, page_url, count(distinct user_id) as distinct_users
  from
  (
    select user_id, tag_frequencia_de_acessos_30_dias,
        case when rank() OVER (PARTITION BY tag_frequencia_de_acessos_30_dias order by count_pages desc) <= 10 then pagePath else 'other' end as page_url
    from 
    (
      select user_id, pagePath, tag_frequencia_de_acessos_30_dias, count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY tag_frequencia_de_acessos_30_dias, pagePath) as count_pages,
      from tb_exit_last_month_join_profile
    )
  )
  group by tag_frequencia_de_acessos_30_dias, page_url
)

select DATEADD(day, -1, date('2023-02-01')) as date, 0 as id_cortex_view, "LOGADO" as logged, tag_frequencia_de_acessos_30_dias, page_url, distinct_users
from tb_final
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two issue with query:

1. extra comma before from, lead to syntax error
2. inner query column name userid while in outer query column name is user_id.
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a comma right before the `from`. The error message was misleading.